# Remove everything before penultimate time character occurs in a string

Tags: php, string

```
$link = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/this/that/ok/";
$link = trim(substr($link, strrpos($link, '/') + 1));
echo $link
```

This will return nothing, as it delete everything before last occurence of / character and its last.

How do I make it returns `ok` from `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/this/that/ok/`

Comment: If you want everything including and after the penultimate "/", wouldn't that give you "ok/"?

Comment: Yeah, it will. But it can be removed with str_replace just before echoing. $link = str_replace("/", "", $link);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) allows you to specify where you start your search.

changing your line to:

```
$newLink = trim(substr($link, strrpos($link, '/', -1) + 1));
```

will start your search one character before the end. As pointed out by @SurrealDreams, you will still need to trim that last `/` off the result (if any) by adding `/` to the characters you trim in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last sign in string if it's a /

```
$link = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/this/that/ok/";

if(strlen($link)== strrpos($link, '/')+1)
    $link = substr_replace($link ,"",-1);

$link = substr($link, strrpos($link, '/') + 1);

echo $link;
```

A better option to split up an URL is to use RegEx maybe. There is a function called [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to to this.